# SSL Error while building Python from sources

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install on my Jetson Nano board (Ubuntu) a specific Python version from sources and get an error which I don't know how to fix this.
I do:

- wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.7/Python-3.5.7.tgz
- tar
- zxvf Python-3.5.7.tgz cd Python-3.5.7
- ./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations
- make

And after some time I recieve:

> 0:34:25 load avg: 1.10 [189/391] test_logging
> --- Logging error --- Got an error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED] sslv3 alert certificate expired
> (_ssl.c:728) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/logging/handlers.py", line
> 1184, in emit
> h.endheaders()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/http/client.py", line 1103,
> in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/http/client.py", line 934,
> in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/http/client.py", line 877,
> in send
> self.connect()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/http/client.py", line 1261,
> in connect
> server_hostname=server_hostname)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/ssl.py", line 385, in
> wrap_socket
> _context=self)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/ssl.py", line 760, in
> **init**
> self.do_handshake()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/ssl.py", line 996, in
> do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/ssl.py", line 641, in
> do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:728) Call
> stack:   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/runpy.py",
> line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/runpy.py", line 85, in
> _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line
> 1833, in 
> main_in_temp_cwd()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line
> 1808, in main_in_temp_cwd
> main()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 873,
> in main
> runtest_accumulate()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 863,
> in runtest_accumulate
> match_tests=ns.match_tests, pgo=ns.pgo)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line
> 1108, in runtest
> pgo=pgo)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line
> 1403, in runtest_inner
> test_runner()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/support/**init**.py",
> line 1565, in inner
> return func(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/test_logging.py", line
> 4298, in test_main
> support.run_unittest(*tests)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/support/**init**.py",
> line 1901, in run_unittest
> _run_suite(suite)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/support/**init**.py",
> line 1857, in _run_suite
> result = runner.run(suite)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/support/**init**.py",
> line 1740, in run
> test(result)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/suite.py", line 84,
> in **call**
> return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/suite.py", line
> 122, in run
> test(result)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/suite.py", line 84,
> in **call**
> return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/suite.py", line
> 122, in run
> test(result)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/case.py", line 653,
> in **call**
> return self.run(*args, **kwds)   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/unittest/case.py", line 605,
> in run
> testMethod()   File "/home/dlinano/Documents/Python-3.5.7/Lib/test/test_logging.py", line
> 1710, in test_output
> logger.error(msg) Message: 'spдm' Arguments: ()

I've never seen this before and there's nothing similar over the internet

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing the keycert.pem file (present under test dir) with the latest keycert.pem available in any Python version greater than Python-3.5.7.

Hopefully that will resolve your problem. I did same it worked for me :)